# Tooltip added by DOM manipulation is unable to render HTML

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am attempting to render the HTML in a tooltip, but unfortunately its not working at all.

This is how it has been programmed:

```
<div class="someField"></div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.someField').append('<a href="#" data-html="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="<ul><li>Wee</li></ul>">(Example)</a>');
        $("body").tooltip({html:true,selector: '[data-toggle=tooltip]'});
    }); 
</script>
```

I have set `data-html="true"` in the link and furthermore enabled html in the tooltip parameter.

Whats wrong with my code?

**UPDATE:**

Bootstrap v2.3.1 is used for this project (old framework).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $("body").tooltip({ html: true, selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]' });
```

## [WORKING DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/uoPPjJsOK2)

Comment: I have tried this, but without any luck. When i look at the behavior via  Chrome Devtool i can see that when the tooltip is rendered there is quotes around the HTML content in the tooltip div, which obviously is the reason why my HTML is not rendered but just shown as plain text.

Comment: What is your exact requirement ?

Comment: I don't want to sound like a jerk, but how is this different from my example?

Comment: Give the tooltip in double quotes "tooltip" in data-toggle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64696/discussion-between-javacake-and-jake745).